# How to prevent P2 to overwrite eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, p2

I'm using eclipse 3.72 (Indigo) for my RCP Application. And it works fine. I've implemented p2 for automated updates. But after using p2 for updating my features my eclipse.ini gets overwritten! How can I disable that?

My customer is able to change the language-settings my prog is using and the -data-param for storing specific data into "@user.home ...". I can't tell him to modify the eclipse.ini after an update is placed.

Answer (score 1):

Advice your customer to introduce the additional program arguments in a separate batch file, which would execute YourEclipseProduct.exe:

```
#!/bin/bash
YourEclipseProduct.exe -data <path>
```

These program arguments will have precedence over those in YourEclipseProduct.ini

I would not recommend messing with P2, since some installed IUs may really need to customize the .ini file.

Comment: This is a major inconvenience. What if you have a dozen customers? You can't be serious going through all the installations and manually modify this.

Comment: Why inconvenience? There is no need for manual changes on every installation. Deliver the batch "root" file with p2 touchpoint, that's all.